# React js, Jsfiddle. Can't handle <img>

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm completely stuck trying to use  tag in React. The picture doesn't render. Please need help. Here's a link and a my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/agenechko/n5u2wwjg/249428/

```
let productCard = <div><img src ={"http://hutorium.ru/img/tasks/product.jpg"}></div>

ReactDOM.render(productCard, document.getElementById("target"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following with no spaces between `src` and `=` as well as a `/` before the closing `>` of `img` to close the `img` tag:

```
let productCard = <div><img src={"http://hutorium.ru/img/tasks/product.jpg"} /></div>;
```

This resolves the error `Unterminated JSX contents` that was occurring in your original example

Update [example](https://jsfiddle.net/Lhe6gfuc/).

Hopefully that helps!